# Shared ptr between two class/headers

Tags: c++

I have two headers/classes, and wanting to share an object between them. Have to dumb it down as I can't share actual work.

**HeaderInitial.h**

```
class HeaderInitial {
public: 
    std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass> ClassObject;
}
```

**HeaderInitial.cpp**

```
void function() {
    ClassObject->randomCall();
}
```

**HeaderShared.h**

```
class HeaderShared {
public: 
    std:shared_ptr<AnotherClass> ClassObject2(ClassObject);
}
```

**HeaderShared.cpp**

```
void function() {
    ClassObject2->randomCall();
}
```

Get errors building the app with this current state. Such as:

> invalid use of member function 'ClassObject2->randomCall()' (did you forget the '()')

Not seeing much online on how this works. Most other options show just a single header file, which I can't do in my scenario for other reasons.

**Update**
Also seeing this error as part of `HeaderShared.h`:

> 'ClassObject' has not been declared

Comment: What is `std:shared_ptr<AnotherClass> ClassObject2<ClassObject>;` ? Makes no sense for me. isn't it `std:shared_ptr<AnotherClass> ClassObject2(ClassObject);`

Comment: It is that, typo.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is `function()` a free function and not a member function? If so, why would you expect `ClassObject2` to mean `HeaderShared::ClassObject2`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've tried `HeaderShared::ClassObject2.randomCall()` and still same error.  The functions are part of a component that I thought would add too much code to my question.

Comment: @bilumer You mean `HeaderShared::ClassObject2->randomCall()`, don't you? The `shared_ptr` doesn't have a member called `randomCall`, the object it points to does.

Comment: You code is very incomplete. Not many people are willing to write the whole code to help you given there are so many mistakes in your code and a lot of minimal code is missing. Essentially in your question, your code should have been very similar to Remy answer except for the errors you didn't understand (and even that, one can usually get help directly from the compiler IDE by pressing F1 for help).

Answer (score 2):

`ClassObject` is a **non-static** member of `HeaderInitial`.

In `HeaderShared`, when constructing `ClassObject2`, you need an object instance of `HeaderInitial` to get `ClassObject` from. So, you can't construct `ClassObject2` the way you are (unless you have a global `HeaderInitial` object).

Otherwise, pass `HeaderShared`'s constructor a reference/pointer to a `HeaderInitial` object, and then `HeaderShared` can construct `ClassObject2` using that object's `ClassObject`, eg:

**HeaderInitial.h**

```cpp
#include <memory>

class AnotherClass;

class HeaderInitial
{
public: 
    std::shared_ptr<AnotherClass> ClassObject;

    void function();
};
```

**HeaderInitial.cpp**

```cpp
#include "HeaderInitial.h"
#include "AnotherClass.h"

void HeaderInitial::function()
{
    ClassObject->randomCall();
}
```

**HeaderShared.h**

```cpp
#include <memory>

class AnotherClass;
class HeaderInitial;

class HeaderShared
{
public: 
    std:shared_ptr<AnotherClass> ClassObject2;

    HeaderShared(HeaderInitial &hdr);
    void function();
};
```

**HeaderShared.cpp**

```cpp
#include "HeaderShared.h"
#include "HeaderInitial.h"
#include "AnotherClass.h"

HeaderShared::HeaderShared(HeaderInitial &hdr)
    : ClassObject2(hdr.ClassObject)
{
}

void HeaderShared::function()
{
    ClassObject2->randomCall();
}
```